# RegisterWaitForSingleObject vs System.Timers

Tags: c#, .net-core, timer, async-await, task-parallel-library

I need my code to execute after waiting for a specific time. This should happen asynchronous without blocking my thread. I searched the web and found many ways to do this. Two options are to use the System.Timers or to use RegisterWaitForSingleObject and a ManualResetEvent.

I couldn't really figure out the difference or when to prefer one over the other.
Can you tell me briefly why and when to use Timers or RegisterWaitForSingleObject with ManualResetEvent?

Sidenote: I'm fond of TAP and TPL and generally prefer those over other patterns (but is this the only reason for not using System.Timer?)

Comment: If you're using async/await, you can use `await Task.Delay(..)`. I've never seen anyone use `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` in C# -- if you need a timer, use a Timer.

Comment: You should use neither of these. [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) is so much easier to write and to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Timers**

You use [Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers) when you want the same code to run multiple times, with a specific amount of time in between.

**RegisterWaitForSingleObject**

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.registerwaitforsingleobject?view=netframework-4.8) says it best:

> Registers a delegate that is waiting for a [WaitHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle?view=netframework-4.8).

And a `WaitHandle` is used when you want to

> wait for exclusive access to shared resources.

If you're not waiting for shared resources, then it's not appropriate for your use case.

**ManualResetEvent**

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.8) says

> Represents a thread synchronization event that, when signaled, must be reset manually.

The "signalling" and "resetting" are things that your code needs to do. It's used when one of your threads needs to signal to another of your threads that it can continue.

**Your use case**

You said:

> I need my code to execute after waiting for a specific time.

If you do not need to repeat the code over and over, and you aren't waiting for shared resources, and you aren't waiting for another thread, then none of the above methods are appropriate.

If you really just need to wait a specific amount of time before moving on, then, as mentioned already, use [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.8):

```
await Task.Delay(5000); //wait 5 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation! Now things are clearer for me. But just to verify: In my case im waiting for a connect response of a remote socket. If I get a positive response in time the timer stops and code continues. But if the response is not in time or negative the connect request repeats after the timeout (infinitely until successful). Can I use Delay in this case? Because you said "If you do not need to repeat the code over and over".

Comment: In that case, you are wait for *something*, not just for time to pass. So it all depends on the code you are using to open the socket and how you know that the response has been received. Sometimes there's an easy way to set a timeout. Other times you have to do that yourself. I'd have to see your code. You might be better off asking a new question at this point, since this really is different than what you asked here.

Comment: I think I'm safe with Delay because I use SocketAsyncEventArgs for the connect operation and dispose it after usage before I try to connect again with a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You use WaitForSingleObject to wait until THE OBJECT is signalled to be in specific state. OR TIMEOUT occurs. So this is not what you want to do. You want your code to be "paused" for a specific amount of time. So "time" here is main result.

I would try to go with await Task.Delay(ms). This looks like the most convinient way to do this nowadays.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me use cases to help me understand? When are WaitForSingleObject appropriate and Task.Delay wouldn't do the job?

Comment: It's like... Task.Delay - wait for some time and then do something. WaitForSingleObject - wait for some object to let you know that it's done it's job and you can do something.